# How to leave white space on both sides of page?

Tags: html, css, background, space

My client wants the background to have white spaces on sides(weird?), but I couldn't find the solution.

Basically I want to have a background and white on sides for wide screens.

NOTE AND IMPORTANT: I need this on body.

How can I do this?

Comment: body {margin:0, padding:0;} ?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this CSS on your `body`

```
body { width: 974px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

The `margin` statement means that you give your `body` a top- and bottom-margin of 0. The `auto`-value means that however much horizontal space remains after you've used up 974px, will be evenly split to add the whitespace on each side of the `body`.

If you don't have a wrapping container like `<header>`, `<section>` that you can apply this width to, you might find yourself a little restricted when it comes to placing content like background-images and such that should display on the sides of the `body`. You will be left with only the `html`-element as a parent to the `body` so that doesn't offer a lot of layers or hooks where you can add advanced styling for decoration and such... just a word of caution :)

Answer (score 4):

You give your container a width (say, `1000px`), and then use `margin: auto` on it.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s29La5qa/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<body class="outerwrapper">
  <div id="innerwrapeer" class="innerwrapeer">
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  width:1024px;
  height:auto;
  background-color:white;
}

.innerwrapeer {
  width:800px;
  height:auto;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Where is `.outerwrapper` in the CSS?